# Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'Buffer' has already been declared

Tags: google-text-to-speech

We have an application running on vite and want to implement text to speech for our users bad at reading. But apparently this doesn't work, as NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin uses Buffer and the google-cloud-text-to-speech does the same. I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'Buffer' has already been declared

Comment: Can you give the code of the application because it is very hard to determine the answer without the code.

Comment: Can't really share the code as it is work, but the issue is. When i dont have the google-cloud-text-to-speech package installed the application starts with no problems, but with the package installed i get the syntax error.